# Typeahead 0.10 prevent caching

Tags: typeahead, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I use twitter's typeahead 0.10 with remote url to retrieve JSON results from server.

I would like to prevent tthe client caching so that the search takes place always on the 
server. How can I do that?

Please see below my code:

```
 // instantiate the bloodhound suggestion engine
    var dataSource = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: function (d) {
            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
        },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: "../" + autocompleteInfo.ControllerName + "/" + autocompleteInfo.MethodName + "?term=%QUERY&ts=" + (new Date().getTime()),
            filter: function (res) {
                var data = [];
                data = $.map(res, function (item) {
                    return { label: item.Name, id: item.Id, autocompleteInfo: autocompleteInfo, cssClass: item.Class };
                });

                return data;
            }
        },
        limit: 15,
        name: 'typeaheadSourceCache',
        ttl: 0,
        ajax: {
            cache: false
        }
    });

    dataSource.initialize();

    $("#" + autocompleteInfo.AutocompleteId).typeahead({
        minLength: 3,
        highlight: true,
        autoselect: true
    },
        { 
            displayKey: 'label',
            source: dataSource.ttAdapter(),
            templates: {
                suggestion: Handlebars.compile(
                '<div class="searchItem {{cssClass}}">{{label}}</div>'
                )
            }
        });
```

Comment: It may be of interest to know that others in the twitter typeahead community have the same problems and solutions are being examined. For example, see: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/pull/703

Comment: see also https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/564

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at version 10.0.2. There is now a means to clear cache via Bloodhound.js (used in association with Typeahead.js):

**engine.clearRemoteCache();**

Here is the documentation from twitter typeahead:
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#bloodhoundclearremotecache

Answer (score 29):

Just add `cache` field to `remote` object:

`remote: {
  'cache': false
  ...
}`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  I had multiple bloodhound engines, tied to multiple text inputs, each serving up a different list of users by role (that's a mouthful).  After choosing a user from one of the three text inputs, the other inputs would show the list of users that the first input had served up.  This was actually logically incorrect for my purposes.  Anyway, thanks Richard.

Comment: This should be selected as the answer. Thanks Richard.

Comment: This should definitely be the selected answer.  Why on earth wasn't this option mentioned under "Remote" in the docs at https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#remote

Comment: This definitely works! Just keep in mind that to refresh the results (in case you added more results to your data source) you have to change at least one letter of the current typeahead search. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use typeahead destroy utils, i think in your case are:

```
$("#" + autocompleteInfo.AutocompleteId).typeahead('destroy');
```

The you reinizialize $("#" + autocompleteInfo.AutocompleteId)

Comment: Thank you. I do not want to destroy and recreate again the typeahead control(or at least the input element used by typeahead), one reason for this being that I don't have a proper event when to do this destroy/create operation. I want for each keyword that is searched, event if it was searched before, to make a request to the server.

Answer (score 0):

To fix IE issues I've came to:

```
remote: {
url: '/myurl?par=%QUERY',
wildcard: '%QUERY',
prepare: function (q, o) {
        o.url = o.url.replace('%QUERY', encodeURIComponent(q));
        o.cache = false;
        return o;
    }
}

prefetch: {
    url: '/myurl2',
    ttl: 300000, //5min
    thumbprint: userName,
    prepare: function(o) {
        o.cache = false;
        return o;
}
```